# Why can't the server recognize what the client is sending?

Tags: android, multithreading, sockets, tcp

I am writing a an Android app which is essentially an network based tic tac toe, There is a server on the computer an two Android phones as clients playing against each other. To accomplish this task I created a multithreaded server that can deal with both clients, and I created the two clients and I made them receive what the server sends them in a separate thread and using a handler I change the UI once the server sends the other player's move.

The problem is that the serverThread never recognizes what any of the clients send. The protocol I am using between the client and the server is a number based protocol, once the client clicks on a tile, a number is sent to the server, the server adds this number to an array, and sends it to all the threads(Both clients) so that they can change this tile from tile to "X" or "O" depending on the number

1. Here is the code for the listener of two buttons, all other buttons are similar

   ```
   b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       public void onClick(View v) {
           if (value == 1) {
               numberSent = 0;
               Global.os.println(Integer.toString(0));
               Global.os.flush();
               Log.i("Sent", "The Zero");
           }
           else if (value == 2) {
               numberSent = 9;
               Global.os.println(Integer.toString(Activity2.numberSent));
               Global.os.flush();
           }
       }
   });

   b2.setImageResource(R.drawable.tile);
   b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       public void onClick(View v) {
           if(value == 1) {
               numberSent = 1;
               Global.os.println(Integer.toString(Activity2.numberSent));
               Global.os.flush();
           }
           else if(value == 2) {
               numberSent = 10;
               Global.os.println(Integer.toString(Activity2.numberSent));
               Global.os.flush();
           }
       }
   });
   ```
2. Here is the code for the ClientThread (The one that handles messages recieved from the server and has the handler that changes the UI)

   ```
   import java.io.DataInputStream;
   import java.io.IOException;
   import java.io.PrintStream;
   import java.net.Socket;
   import java.net.UnknownHostException;
   import android.util.Log;

   public class ClientThread implements Runnable {
       int s;
       public void run() {
           try {
               try {
                   Global.s = new Socket("10.0.2.2", 5555);
                   Global.is = new DataInputStream(Global.s.getInputStream());
                   Global.os = new PrintStream(Global.s.getOutputStream());
                   Global.os.println(Integer.toString(100));
                   Log.i("Socket", "Created");
               } catch (Exception e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
               }
               while (true) {
                   Log.i("In the", "While");
                   try {
                       String S = null;
                       while ((S = Global.is.readLine()) != null) {
                           Log.d("ServerActivity", "line");
                           Activity2.handler.post(new Runnable() {
                               @Override
                               public void run() {
                                   Global.os.print(Integer.toString(Activity2.numberSent));
                                   try {
                                       String S = Global.is.readLine();
                                       s = Integer.parseInt(S);
                                       if (s == 0) {
                                           Activity2.handler.post(new Runnable() {
                                               @Override
                                               public void run() {
                                                   Activity2.b1.setImageResource(R.drawable.x);
                                               }
                                           });
                                       }
                                       else if(s == 1){
                                           Activity2.handler.post(new Runnable() {
                                               @Override
                                               public void run() {
                                                   Activity2.b2.setImageResource(R.drawable.x);
                                               }
                                           });
                                       }
                                       else if(s == 2){
                                           Activity2.handler.post(new Runnable() {
                                               @Override
                                               public void run() {
                                                   Activity2.b3.setImageResource(R.drawable.x);
                                               }
                                           });
                                       }
                                       else if(s == 3){
                                           Activity2.handler.post(new Runnable() {
                                               @Override
                                               public void run() {
                                                   Activity2.b4.setImageResource(R.drawable.x);
                                               }
                                           });
                                       }
                                       else if(s == 4){
                                           Activity2.handler.post(new Runnable() {
                                               @Override
                                               public void run() {
                                                   Activity2.b5.setImageResource(R.drawable.x);
                                               }
                                           });
                                       }
                                       else if(s == 5){
                                           Activity2.handler.post(new Runnable() {
                                               @Override
                                               public void run() {
                                                   Activity2.b6.setImageResource(R.drawable.x);
                                               }
                                           });
                                       }
                                       else if(s == 6){
                                           Activity2.handler.post(new Runnable() {
                                               @Override
                                               public void run() {
                                                   Activity2.b7.setImageResource(R.drawable.x);
                                               }
                                           });
                                       }
                                       else if(s == 7){
                                           Activity2.handler.post(new Runnable() {
                                               @Override
                                               public void run() {
                                                   Activity2.b8.setImageResource(R.drawable.x);
                                               }
                                           });
                                       }
                                       else if(s == 8){
                                           Activity2.handler.post(new Runnable() {
                                               @Override
                                               public void run() {
                                                   Activity2.b9.setImageResource(R.drawable.x);
                                               }
                                           });
                                       }
                                       else if(s == 9){
                                           Activity2.handler.post(new Runnable() {
                                               public void run() {
                                                   Activity2.b1.setImageResource(R.drawable.o);
                                               }
                                           });
                                       }
                                       else if(s == 10){
                                           Activity2.handler.post(new Runnable() {
                                               public void run() {
                                                   Activity2.b2.setImageResource(R.drawable.o);
                                               }
                                           });
                                       }
                                       else if(s == 11){
                                           Activity2.handler.post(new Runnable() {
                                               @Override
                                               public void run() {
                                                   Activity2.b3.setImageResource(R.drawable.o);
                                               }
                                           });
                                       }
                                       else if(s == 12){
                                           Activity2.handler.post(new Runnable() {
                                               @Override
                                               public void run() {
                                                   Activity2.b4.setImageResource(R.drawable.o);
                                               }
                                           });
                                       }
                                       else if(s == 13){
                                           Activity2.handler.post(new Runnable() {
                                               @Override
                                               public void run() {
                                                   Activity2.b5.setImageResource(R.drawable.o);
                                               }
                                           });
                                       }
                                       else if(s == 14){
                                           Activity2.handler.post(new Runnable() {
                                               @Override
                                               public void run() {
                                                   Activity2.b6.setImageResource(R.drawable.o);
                                               }
                                           });
                                       }
                                       else if(s == 15){
                                           Activity2.handler.post(new Runnable() {
                                               @Override
                                               public void run() {
                                                   Activity2.b7.setImageResource(R.drawable.o);
                                               }
                                           });
                                       }
                                       else if(s == 16){
                                           Activity2.handler.post(new Runnable() {
                                               @Override
                                               public void run() {
                                                   Activity2.b8.setImageResource(R.drawable.o);
                                               }
                                           });
                                       }
                                       else if(s == 17){
                                           Activity2.handler.post(new Runnable() {
                                               @Override
                                               public void run() {
                                                   Activity2.b9.setImageResource(R.drawable.o);
                                               }
                                           });
                                       }
                                       else {
                                       }
                                   } catch (IOException e) {
                                       e.printStackTrace();
                                   }
                               });
                           }
                       } catch (Exception e) {
                           Log.e("ClientActivity", "S: Error", e);
                   }
               }
           } catch (Exception e) {
               Log.e("ClientActivity", "C: Error", e);
           }
       }
   }
   ```
3. Here is the code of my server thread

   ```
   import java.io.DataInputStream;
   import java.io.IOException;
   import java.io.PrintStream;
   import java.net.Socket;

   class ServerThread extends Thread {
       DataInputStream is = null;
       PrintStream os = null;
       Socket clientSocket = null;
       ServerThread t[];
       public String received;

       public ServerThread(Socket clientSocket, ServerThread[] t){
           this.clientSocket=clientSocket;
           this.t=t;
       }

       public void run() {
           try {
               is = new DataInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
           } catch (IOException e1) {
               e1.printStackTrace();
           }
       try {
           os = new PrintStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
       } catch (IOException e1) {
           e1.printStackTrace();
       }
       try{
           // Once the socket is open all the work will be here!!!!!!

           while(true) {
               System.out.print("In the while");
               received = is.readLine();
               int s = Integer.parseInt(received);
               if(s == 100) {
                   System.out.print("I recieved the 100");
               }
               if(s == 0) {
                   System.out.println("I recieved the 0");
                   XOServer.boardArray[0] = 1;
                   XOServer.turn = true;
                   for(int i = 0; i<=t.length; i++) {
                       if (t[i]!=null) {
                           XOServer.sentValue = 0;
                           t[i].os.println(Integer.toString(XOServer.sentValue));
                           t[i].os.flush();
                       }
                   }
               }
               else if(s == 1) {
                   XOServer.boardArray[1] = 1;
                   XOServer.turn = true;
                   for(int i = 0; i<=t.length; i++) {
                       if (t[i]!=null) {
                           XOServer.sentValue = 1;
                           t[i].os.println(Integer.toString(XOServer.sentValue));
                           t[i].os.flush();
                       }
                   }
               }
               else if(s == 2) {
                   XOServer.boardArray[2] = 1;
                   XOServer.turn = true;
                   for(int i = 0; i<=t.length; i++) {
                       if (t[i]!=null) {
                           XOServer.sentValue = 2;
                           t[i].os.println(Integer.toString(XOServer.sentValue));
                           t[i].os.flush();
                       }
                   }
               }
               else if(s == 3) {
                   XOServer.boardArray[3] = 1;
                   XOServer.turn = true;
                   for(int i = 0; i<=t.length; i++) {
                       if (t[i]!=null) {
                           XOServer.sentValue = 3;
                           t[i].os.println(Integer.toString(XOServer.sentValue));
                           t[i].os.flush();
                       }
                   }
               }
               else if(s == 4) {
                   XOServer.boardArray[4] = 1;
                   XOServer.turn = true;
                   for(int i = 0; i<=t.length; i++) {
                       if (t[i]!=null) {
                           XOServer.sentValue = 4;
                           t[i].os.println(Integer.toString(XOServer.sentValue));
                           t[i].os.flush();
                       }
                   }
               }
               else if(s == 5) {
                   XOServer.boardArray[5] = 1;
                   XOServer.turn = true;
                   for(int i = 0; i<=t.length; i++) {
                       if (t[i]!=null) {
                           XOServer.sentValue = 5;
                           t[i].os.println(Integer.toString(XOServer.sentValue));
                           t[i].os.flush();
                       }
                   }
               }
               else if(s == 6) {
                   XOServer.boardArray[6] = 1;
                   XOServer.turn = true;
                   for(int i = 0; i<=t.length; i++) {
                       if (t[i]!=null) {
                           XOServer.sentValue = 6;
                           t[i].os.println(Integer.toString(XOServer.sentValue));
                           t[i].os.flush();
                       }
                   }
               }
               else if(s == 7) {
                   XOServer.boardArray[7] = 1;
                   XOServer.turn = true;
                   System.out.print("I recieved the 7");
                   for(int i = 0; i<=t.length; i++) {
                       if (t[i]!=null) {
                           XOServer.sentValue = 7;
                           t[i].os.println(Integer.toString(XOServer.sentValue));
                           t[i].os.flush();
                       }
                   }
               }
               else if(s == 8) {
                   XOServer.boardArray[8] = 1;
                   XOServer.turn = true;
                   for(int i = 0; i<=t.length; i++) {
                       if (t[i]!=null) {
                           XOServer.sentValue = 8;
                           t[i].os.println(Integer.toString(XOServer.sentValue));
                           t[i].os.flush();
                       }
                   }
               }
               else if(s == 9) {
                   XOServer.boardArray[0] = 2;
                   XOServer.turn = false;
                   for(int i = 0; i<=t.length; i++) {
                       if (t[i]!=null) {
                           XOServer.sentValue = 9;
                           t[i].os.println(Integer.toString(XOServer.sentValue));
                           t[i].os.flush();
                       }
                   }
               }
               else if(s == 10) {
                   XOServer.boardArray[1] = 2;
                   XOServer.turn = false;
                   for(int i = 0; i<=t.length; i++) {
                       if (t[i]!=null) {
                           XOServer.sentValue = 10;
                           t[i].os.println(Integer.toString(XOServer.sentValue));
                           t[i].os.flush();
                       }
                   }
               }
               else if(s == 11) {
                   XOServer.boardArray[2] = 2;
                   XOServer.turn = false;
                   for(int i = 0; i<=t.length; i++) {
                       if (t[i]!=null) {
                           XOServer.sentValue = 11;
                           t[i].os.println(Integer.toString(XOServer.sentValue));
                           t[i].os.flush();
                       }
                   }
               }
               else if(s == 12) {
                   XOServer.boardArray[3] = 2;
                   XOServer.turn = false;
                   for(int i = 0; i<=t.length; i++) {
                       if (t[i]!=null) {
                           XOServer.sentValue = 12;
                           t[i].os.println(Integer.toString(XOServer.sentValue));
                           t[i].os.flush();
                       }
                   }
               }
               else if(s == 13) {
                   XOServer.boardArray[4] = 2;
                   XOServer.turn = false;
                   for(int i = 0; i<=t.length; i++) {
                       if (t[i]!=null) {
                           XOServer.sentValue = 13;
                           t[i].os.println(Integer.toString(XOServer.sentValue));
                           t[i].os.flush();
                       }
                   }
               }
               else if(s == 14) 
                   XOServer.boardArray[5] = 2;
                   XOServer.turn = false;
                   for(int i = 0; i<=t.length; i++) {
                       if (t[i]!=null) {
                           XOServer.sentValue = 14;
                           t[i].os.println(Integer.toString(XOServer.sentValue));
                           t[i].os.flush();
                       }
                   }
               }
               else if(s == 15) {
                   XOServer.boardArray[6] = 2;
                   XOServer.turn = false;
                   for(int i = 0; i<=t.length; i++) {
                       if (t[i]!=null) {
                           XOServer.sentValue = 15;
                           t[i].os.println(Integer.toString(XOServer.sentValue));
                           t[i].os.flush();
                       }
                   }
               }
               else if(s == 16) {
                   XOServer.boardArray[7] = 2;
                   XOServer.turn = false;
                   for(int i = 0; i<=t.length; i++) {
                       if (t[i]!=null) {
                           XOServer.sentValue = 16;
                           t[i].os.println(Integer.toString(XOServer.sentValue));
                           t[i].os.flush();
                       }
                   }
               }
               else if(s == 17) {
                   XOServer.boardArray[8] = 2;
                   XOServer.turn = false;
                   for(int i = 0; i<=t.length; i++) {
                       if (t[i]!=null) {
                           XOServer.sentValue = 17;
                           t[i].os.println(Integer.toString(XOServer.sentValue));
                           t[i].os.flush();
                       }
                   }
               }
               else {
               }
           }
       }
       catch (Exception e){
           System.out.print(e);
       }
   }
   ```
4. Here is the code for my server

   ```
   import java.io.DataInputStream;
   import java.io.IOException;
   import java.io.InputStream;
   import java.io.PrintStream;
   import java.net.ServerSocket;
   import java.net.Socket;

   public class XOServer{
       // Declaration section:
       // declare a server socket and a client socket for the server
       // declare an input and an output stream

       static  Socket clientSocket = null;
       static  ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
       static PrintStream os = null;
       static DataInputStream is = null;
       static int sentValue;

       // This chat server can accept up to 10 clients' connections
       static  ServerThread t[] = new ServerThread[10];
       public static int [] boardArray = new int[9];
       public static boolean turn = false;

       public static void main(String args[]) {
           // The default port
           int port_number=5555;

           if (args.length < 1) {
               System.out.println("Usage: java MultiThreadChatServer \n"+
                   "Now using port number="+port_number);
           } else {
               port_number=Integer.valueOf(args[0]).intValue();
           }
           for(int i = 0; i <=8; i++ ) {
               boardArray[i] = 0;
           }

           // Initialization section:
           // Try to open a server socket on port port_number (default 2222)
           // Note that we can't choose a port less than 1023 if we are not
           // privileged users (root)

           try {
               serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port_number);
           }
           catch (IOException e) {
               System.out.println(e);
           }

           // Create a socket object from the ServerSocket to listen and accept
           // connections.
           // Open input and output streams for this socket will be created in
           // client's thread since every client is served by the server in
           // an individual thread

           while (true) {
               try {
                   clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
                   is = new DataInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
                   os = new PrintStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());

                   for(int i=0; i<=9; i++){
                       if(t[i]==null) {
                           (t[i] = new ServerThread(clientSocket,t)).start();
                           break;
                       }
                   }
               }
               catch (IOException e) {
                   System.out.println(e);
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Is `Global.os` global and used by all threads?  It should not be.  It should be per-thread.

Comment: Are you calling flush after you write something out?

Comment: The code is too long, yes. But it is kinda easy to understand as it is all if conditions:) Global is a class in the package that has the socket s InputStream is, and the OutputStream os, as static variables

Comment: Yes, I do call flush every single time I write something on Global.os

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem (or at least one problem) is on the server.  When the client connects you  are setting:

```
os = new PrintStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
```

`os` is a static variable inside of the server.  This is wrong.

```
static PrintStream os
```

Each client thread *must* have it's own separate `PrintStream`.  You will need to get the input/output streams and pass them into your handler.

```
    clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
    DataInputStream is = new DataInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
    PrintStream os = new PrintStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
    ... new ServerThread(is, os, clientSocket, t)).start();
```

Also, I don't understand why you fork 10 threads for each client connection.  That seems wrong.  Typically you could accept a client connection and then fork 1 thread to handle that specific connection with that input and output streams.